# MongoDB map filtered array inside another array with aggregate $project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo

I am using Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB with Pymongo. My goal is to filter array inside array and return only filtered results. Aggregation query works for the first array, but returns full inside array after using map, filter operations. Please find Reproducible Example in Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zS8A7zDMrmK

Current query use `$project` to filter and return result by selected `Options` but still returns every object in `Discount_Price` although query has additional filter to check if  it has specific `Sales_Week` value.

Let me know in comments if my question is clear, many thanks for all possible help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed you troubled in filtering nested array.

```
options:{
    $filter: {
        input: {
            $map: {
                input: "$Sales_Options",
                as: 's',
                in: {
                    City: "$$s.City",
                    Country: "$$s.Country",
                    Discount_Price: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$$s.Discount_Price",
                            as: "d",
                            cond: {
                                $in: ["$$d.Sales_Week", [2, 7]]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        as: 'pair',
        cond: {
            $and: [{
                    $in: [
                        '$$pair.Country',
                        [
                            'UK'
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $in: [
                        '$$pair.City',
                        [
                            'London'
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Working [Mongo plaground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dMbFsR3BGga). If you need price1, you can use `$project` in next stage.

Note : If you follow the projection form upper stage use `1` or `0` which is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I'd steer you towards the `$unwind` operator and everything becomes a lot simpler:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"Store": "AB"}},
  {$unwind: "$Sales_Options"},
  {$unwind: "$Sales_Options.Discount_Price"},
  {$match: {"Sales_Options.Country": {$in: [ "UK" ]},
            "Sales_Options.City": {$in: [ "London" ]},  
            "Sales_Options.Discount_Price.Sales_Week": {$in: [ 2, 7 ]}
           }
  }
])
```

Now just `$project` the fields as appropriate for your output.